Commutativity question in 5.40 Proof in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition)
I am trying to understand a proof within Axler's book, but part of his proof makes use of seemingly unexplained claims. I suspect the narrative thread was broken during the update to a new version or, more likely, I simply missed an important point.
I'm referring to the proof of 5.40 equation satisfied by operator with upper-triangular matrix:
Suppose $T: V \to V$ is a linear operator on vector space $V$ with a basis resulting in an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Then
$$
(T-\lambda_1 I)\ldots (T-\lambda_n I)=0
$$
Proof: Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ denote a basis of $V$ with respect to which $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then $T(v_1)=\lambda_1 v$, which means that $(T-\lambda_1 I)(v_1)=0$, which implies that $(T-\lambda_1 I)\ldots(T-\lambda_m I)(v_1)=0$ for $m=1,\ldots,n$ (using the commutativity of each $T-\lambda_j I$ with each $T-\lambda_k I$)...
QUESTION: The proof continues but what I don't understand is why each $T-\lambda_j I$ can be considered commutative with each $T-\lambda_k I$. Axler makes it clear that the product of linear operators is not necessarily commutative, and I could not find where he makes the case that this particular product would be. This is the one aspect of the proof preventing me from completely understanding it, so any help is greatly appreciated.
ANSWER EDIT: The comment by terran regarding 5.17 helped me recreate the narrative thread I had overlooked.
Basically, a polynomial $p$ can take an operator $T$ as input rather than the usual real/complex scalar, such that
$$p(T)=a_0I+a_1T+\ldots+a_m T^m$$
This polynomial applied to operators has this property (paraphrased):
Suppose $p,q$ are polynomials applied to the operator $T$. Then

$(pq)(T)=p(T)q(T)$
$p(T)q(T)=q(T)p(T)$

The above was the missing link for me. If $p(z)=z-\lambda_j$ and $q(z)=z-\lambda_k$, then $p(T)=T-\lambda_j I$ and $q(T)=T-\lambda_k I$ and by the above $p(T)q(T)=q(T)p(T)$, explaining the use of commutativity in the original proof.

Check result 5.17, which states that $p(T) q(T) = q(T) p(T)$ for polynomials $p, q$

Or simply, expand $(T-aI)(T-bI)$.

Commutativity indicates that $AB=BA$ , where we want $A=(T-\lambda_j I)$ & $B=(T-\lambda_k I)$ : We can easily check that $(T-\lambda_j I)(T-\lambda_k I)$ is indeed$(T-\lambda_k I)(T-\lambda_j I)$

Eventually , it is just using the Commutativity of real numbers : $\lambda_j * \lambda_k$ is $\lambda_k * \lambda_j$ : Nothing more to it.

@terran that was it, the important point I missed. Edited question to include that tidbit.

Every linear operator commutes with itself. Also, every linear operator commutes with the identity map and, more generally, with every scalar multiple of the identity map. Therefore, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars, $T-\alpha I$ and $T-\beta I$ commute.
